# Unable to load the word2vec file

Tags: python, pandas, list, word2vec

I have a dataset that consists of two columns skill,skill_id. I performed groupby on the columns based on skill_id in order to group similar words. I have applied word2vec by converting the skill column to list. The model has been saved in text format. When I am trying to load, I am facing the following issue. As I am new to word2vec, I am not able to understand.

My intention on groupby is to gather similar words for every unique skill id and get a vector for each skill word and apply the average. so that I get one vector for each id.

the code I used is

```
num_worker = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Bigger_list=[]
for i in df['skill']:
    li = list(i.split(","))
    Bigger_list.append(li)
    
model= Word2Vec(Bigger_list, window=2, min_count=2,size=100,hs=1,iter=10,sg=1,sample=6e-5, alpha=0.03, min_alpha=0.0007, workers=num_worker)

print(model)

model.wv.save_word2vec_format(r'myfilepath\word2vec_model.txt', binary=False)
```

My code to load the model

```
model_imp = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r'myfilepath\word2vec_model.txt', binary=False)
```

I am facing the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21008\3971896729.py in <module>
----> 1 model_imp = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r'myfilepath\word2vec_model.txt', binary=False)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
   1496         return _load_word2vec_format(
   1497             cls, fname, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, encoding=encoding, unicode_errors=unicode_errors,
-> 1498             limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
   1499 
   1500     def get_keras_embedding(self, train_embeddings=False):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py in _load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
    392                 parts = utils.to_unicode(line.rstrip(), encoding=encoding, errors=unicode_errors).split(" ")
    393                 if len(parts) != vector_size + 1:
--> 394                     raise ValueError("invalid vector on line %s (is this really the text format?)" % line_no)
    395                 word, weights = parts[0], [datatype(x) for x in parts[1:]]
    396                 add_word(word, weights)

ValueError: invalid vector on line 2 (is this really the text format?)
```

Please let me know where I am making a mistake. And my data is in the following format

```
    skill_id    skill
0   1.0     qlikview business intelligence
1   11.0    sap business objects,business objects,business...
2   25.0    real estate asset management
3   42.0    agile product owner , agile product owner,agil...
4   34.0    koor directie,koordirectie,choral conducting
```

The following are first few embeddings of my saved text file

```
60 100
a -0.0027519886 -0.00442903 -0.001118564 0.003444936 -0.002712117 -0.0019045715 -0.0016266255 -0.0014701005 -0.0025199363 -0.0007534366 -0.004901407 -0.0020701648 0.0019331921 -0.0029777086 0.0038345307 -0.0008459282 0.0017387706 -0.0010123601 0.0014658135 0.0029947227 0.0019565157 -0.0011206624 0.0017488806 -0.0048572565 -0.0046893475 0.0031473283 0.0017187577 -0.00010454104 0.00011814202 0.0011573153 -0.0032775032 -0.0045120628 -0.00083030615 -0.0017424638 0.0009858096 0.0020879856 0.004381688 -0.0016391367 -0.0021372868 -0.0037518719 0.00281201 -0.0020148605 -0.0028737097 0.0013232194 -0.00085448555 0.003938771 0.0002126721 0.0048614475 0.0019287885 0.0024258855 0.00170845 0.0003994863 -0.0010782445 0.0015077748 0.00039399372 -0.0030793473 0.0032820643 -0.0013353502 -0.002382094 0.0028348 0.00422588 0.004865567 -0.0045772456 -0.0007244905 -0.0045920396 -0.0009053842 -0.004434215 -0.004652101 0.0009482954 -0.0021637836 0.0026612186 -0.00064998964 0.0045692804 -0.0022300307 0.0008892211 -0.0024421057 0.0038106074 0.002972011 0.0047947047 -0.003579005 0.0020622176 -0.0015003113 -0.0048827115 0.001435697 -0.001426067 0.0024402055 -0.0024313165 0.0011486546 0.0030393335 0.0044555315 -0.0029097921 0.0018179851 0.0044933013 -0.0034462842 0.0049352064 0.002139891 0.0016969276 0.0047838097 0.003991734 0.0037867466
c 0.0020933063 0.0029840772 0.003953115 -0.0045937877 0.004439451 0.0017167297 0.002534987 0.0014722709 0.0011841966 -0.0005520862 0.000107694264 0.004716349 0.0017393216 -0.004622571 -0.0020550005 0.0013995493 -0.004661933 -0.0044412212 -0.00028131314 0.0019383882 0.0028024118 -0.004549108 -0.0043098805 -0.00057921663 -0.00034584766 0.00022097069 -0.00061436114 -0.00010021048 0.0040966165 0.001350825 0.002894003 0.0043129 0.004502682 0.0031545085 0.00481537 0.00022245632 -0.00041915002 -0.0031378255 -0.0012841591 0.0026570235 0.0033377502 0.002881821 -0.0017221102 0.0021004737 -0.00075394573 0.0033468008 -0.0009578629 0.00082569005 0.002582 -0.0026939583 0.0007758247 0.0025301005 0.0048407214 0.0022507408 0.0029586663 -0.0049211164 -0.0005019555 0.004271891 -0.004325369 -0.0023747026 -0.0014658013 -0.0021614681 0.00419706 0.0008860593 0.00024018806 0.0039277934 -0.0022232481 0.000165361 -0.0017379677 -0.0038237937 -1.8005347e-05 0.0025610244 -0.00311421 0.0033580295 -0.0022040643 -0.002917623 -0.00211762 0.0048241713 0.003904853 0.0037655567 6.413521e-05 -0.0021271573 0.002846656 -0.0024510627 0.0024677755 0.004776053 0.002954335 0.002037779 0.004936806 0.0049951817 -0.0008846737 0.00065424456 0.0019941074 -0.0010205058 -0.0014362748 0.0009993223 0.0029943848 0.0018774081 -0.0028822008 -0.0015683477
visual c -0.0032233796 -0.003269438 0.0046962313 -0.0046262913 -0.004835365 0.00087617757 0.0008411623 -0.00010811405 0.0004916909 -0.0041127736 0.002027938 -0.0009225794 -0.00027192102 0.0014380432 0.0041013444 -0.0009958538 -0.00030296814 0.0041423584 0.002882271 -0.0005628017 0.0018922116 -0.0012261741 -0.0026572372 0.0014662328 0.0026795575 0.0007527587 -0.0043236525 0.0030198894 -0.0013108188 -0.0041076494 -0.0026648848 -0.0041767745 0.0011256622 0.003598196 0.0009959674 0.0007743469 -0.0036901121 -0.004738781 -0.00016525858 -0.0044888584 0.004033749 0.004932975 0.0032606923 -0.0044442746 0.003869201 0.004810709 0.003844858 -0.0013703184 0.0036292472 -0.0041097077 0.0004404855 -0.0041797645 0.0015426256 0.0029095092 0.0027323638 0.0033064622 -0.0012451228 0.0025636333 -0.0024699266 0.00016707332 -0.00019455382 -0.0045830165 0.003518602 0.00043774056 0.0017915597 -0.003692051 0.0009216409 -0.0031137452 0.0048583094 -0.0015011152 -0.0004098041 0.002152557 0.0013405283 -0.0018215863 0.00069950573 -0.0011393798 -0.002741393 0.0018015298 0.0038894769 0.00012525535 0.001333448 -0.00051039783 -0.0033119584 -0.0005765594 0.00075549487 -0.0035012227 0.0012493182 0.0040510437 0.0046862755 0.0020143918 -0.0048689446 -0.0011000098 0.0039440505 0.003450958 -0.0003960383 -0.0038673286 -0.004648333 -0.0049945563 -0.0047375546 -0.0026336329
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text file `word2vec_model.txt` looks anything like your example data format...

```
    skill_id    skill
0   1.0     qlikview business intelligence
1   11.0    sap business objects,business objects,business...
```

...then that's not a word2vec model at all.

On the other hand, if you are just trying to re-load a file that you just saved using `.save_word2vec_format(filename, binary=False)`, then that should work without such an error.

Are you sure the file is the same file that was just saved, with no intervening edits?

Can you check, & share (by editing into your question), the 1st 3 lines of the file? (On many systems, but maybe not whatever Windows-based stuff you're using, this would just the output of the command-line `head -3 word2vec_model.txt`.)

It should be one first line with a count-of-vectors & a count-of-vector-size, then a line each for the 1st 2 word-vectors: a word, then 100 decimal numbers. If it's anything else, it's the wrong format.

---

**Update:** From your shared file excerpt, I see the likely cause: some of your 'words' (actually multi-word skil tokens) include spaces inside them. The `word2vec_format` assumes all words lack whitespace, and uses spaces alone to separate the leading word from later dimensions. So your third 'word' (numbers 2 in 0-based numbering) is `'visual c'` - which gets misread as the word `'visual'` followed by 101 dimensions (too many), the first dimension being `'c'` instead of a real value.

Two options to work-around:

- in your tokenization, for each token, replace the spaces with `'_'`, so the tokens are runs-of-non-space-characters. Then, saving/loading as `word2vec_format` will work – but you'll have to remember to perform or revrse that underscore-modification as appropriate for display/etc.
- use Gensim's native (pickle-based) save/load instead: save with `model.wv.save(filename)`, load with `model = KeyedVectors.load(filename)`. Remember that the save may create more-than-one file, and all such files should be kept alongside each other (if moved/copied) for the load of the main file to succeed.

Separately, if you really only have 60 unique tokens (as your header suggests), note that it's not reasonable to try training a 100-dimensional model with so few unique words. You'd probably want 10,000 or more distinct words to really "fill" a 100-dimensional dense embedding space. (Using too many dimensions risks severe *overfitting*, where the model mainly memorizes idiosyncracies in the training data, rather than learning generalizable things that'd still apply to new data. Real learning usually has some aspect of *compression*, boiling the input down into a smaller-number of helpful patterns.)

---

Separate from your main problem, you `Word2Vec` training shows a lot of suboptimal practices. Specifically regarding:

```
model = Word2Vec(Bigger_list, window=2, min_count=2,size=100,hs=1,iter=10,sg=1,sample=6e-5, alpha=0.03, min_alpha=0.0007, workers=num_worker)
```

- Using such a low `min_count=2` value is usually a bad idea. Tokens with so few examples don't get good vectors – and in fact even worsen vectors for the tokens around them (as the model is spending time/space on words with insufficient examples). If you think you need such a low value, it's likely you need much more training data for best results – enough so that all relevant tokens have 5 more more varied usage examples (for the usual `min_count=5` default), and you don't mind discarding the tokens with fewer examples.
- If, as I suspect, your `skills` are a list where all tokens are equal – the ordering, and which skills are listed next-to each other, isn't important but rather just random/arbitrary – that would usually suggest using a *larger* `window`. Indeed, you might even want to make it gigantic – larger than the number of tokens in any text – so that every skill on the same row can participate in the context of every other skill equally.
- You should essentially never enable hierarchical-softmax mode (`hs=1`) unless you *also* disable the default negative-sampling (with `negative=0`). (But in most cases, the default of negative-sampling probably doesn't need to be changed at all.)
- There's essentially no reason to use weird values for the `alpha` learning-rate max/min like `alpha=0.03, min_alpha=0.0007`. They're not different enough from the defaults to make much difference in results, and only advanced users, who are searching over many possible parameters, should ever be tinkering with these values at all. Whenever I see someone using these values, I'm pretty sure they're copying from a *bad* tutorial. When I see them in a tutorial, they's a pretty strong indication the author isn't good at `Word2Vec` & is just themselves copying from other bad examples without much understanding. IF YOU SEE SUCH VALUES IN AN ONLINE GUIDE – WITHOUT A CLEAR NEARBY RATIONALE – I WOULD RUN IN THE OTHER DIRECTION TO FIND OTHER EXAMPLES BY MORE-COMPETENT AUTHORS.

Comment: my word2vec format is not the same as my text file data mentioned above. I got 100d for each word in the list. As mentioned earlier I am new to word2vec, I just tried some random values with parameters to test how it works. I will take into consideration your suggestions thank you.

Comment: Can you share the 1st 3 lines of the file that's giving you problems?

Comment: I have added the first 3 lines in the description. Can you please check it.  Also can you please suggest to me how can I get each vector of every skill which are present in a single row and get the sum or avg of it, so that each skill id has one vector.

Comment: Thanks! I see an issue, and have expanded the answer (the **Update:** in the middle) to explain the likely problem & workarounds. (And, note another possible issue.)

Comment: thank you for your response. I will take all the considerations and work out on my data. And I have a doubt, how can we get one vector value for each token word after applying the word2vec. I am trying to do average but not sure whether it's the correct process or not. Can you please suggest me

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Every token that appears at least `min_count` times in your traiing data will receive a trained vector, that you can look up. If you have a multi-token text – such as one of your training rows – you can look up each token's vector. If you needed to summarize that row, you could average all the vectors together, as one simple baseline approach, but there are other ways to treat the text as a bag-of-vectors, or learn some separate vector as if it were a document. What you might try would depend on your resources & goals.